# How to override adminhtml block file in Magento 2

Tags: overrides, magento-2.2.1, override-block

How to override module-customer/block/AdminHtml/Group/Edit/Form.php

I have created custom module for that please find my code for that.

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form">
    <plugin name="add_form_field" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Model\Plugin\Form" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Group\Save">
    <plugin name="save_field" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Model\Plugin\Form" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Group\Edit" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit" />  
</config>
```

> Vendor/Package/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit.Form.php

```
<?php 
namespace ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

 class Form extends Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit
 {

public function _prepareLayout()
{
    echo "Layout Worked Successfully..."; die();
}

}
```

There are below exceptions but can't find solutions for them.

> 2 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group
>   Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Block\Adminhtml\Group does not exist

Please guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

## **Override Adminhtml Of

- Block

- Controller**

[image]

**On Image You Can See We Are Overriding the

-  Adminhtml of Block File

- Adminhtml of Controller File**

## **etc\adminhtml\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<preference
    for="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\DeleteButton"
    type="Custom_Vendor\Custom_Module\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\DeleteButton"/>

<preference
    for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Delete"
    type="Custom_Vendor\Custom_Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Delete"/>

<preference
    for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete"
    type="Custom_Vendor\Custom_Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete"/>
```

**Basically Here I am explaining about the file location where you need to Keep Your File (Any Override Related to Adminhtml ). Here I am Using My File You Can Use As Per Your Requirement**

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your block file

> Vendor/Package/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit.Form.php

```
<?php 
namespace ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
//Add "/" in start of extends
 class Form extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit
 {

public function _prepareLayout()
{
    echo "Layout Worked Successfully..."; die();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code to override block file

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form" />
</config>
```

**Vendor/Package/Block/Adminhtml/Group/Edit/Form.php**

```
<?php 
namespace ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;

 class Form extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit
 {

public function _prepareLayout()
{
    echo "Layout Worked Successfully..."; die();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is It important to white controller, if i want to extends only Block/Adminhtml